# Problem with NGINX proxying certain urls to nodejs server for SSR for an angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, server-side-rendering

I have an angular app and use NGINX in production.

My website's Core web vitals are not good and for that reason I have a route in my node.js
application where certain urls are proxied to go to my ssr route in nodejs app where it uses puppeteer to render those urls and then cache it.

I only proxy requests from bots such as googlebot, twitterbot etc to ssr route for pre rendering and caching results.

Now, everything is working correctly for bots but when I remove bots condition from my nginx configuration and then all the requests for a certain url goes through ssr route, then the browser request goes into a loop and requests never complete. Could you please me guide me if my NGINX configuration is correct.

My NGINX configuration is this:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g
inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

# HTTP - Redirect all traffic to HTTPS non-www
server {
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;
      server_name example.com www.example.com;
      return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - Redirect all traffic from www to HTTPS non-www
server {
      listen 443 ssl http2;
      listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
      server_name www.example.com;
      return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

      # SSL Certs
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
}

# HTTPS
server {
      listen 443 ssl http2;
      listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
      server_name example.com;

      # SSL Certs
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

      root /var/www/example.com/html;

      index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

      location ^~ /usecase/ {
        try_files $uri @usecase_prerender;
      }
      
      location @usecase_prerender {
        # If I set $usecase_prerender var to 1 initially or remove if condition and route all /usecase requests to ssr, 
        # then browser requests timeout, and this is where I think the problem arises
        set $usecase_prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest\/0\.|pinterestbot|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|whatsapp|chrome-lighthouse") {
            set $usecase_prerender 1;
        }

        if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
            set $usecase_prerender 0;
        }
        
        #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        if ($usecase_prerender = 1) {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5100/api/ssr/usecase?url=$scheme://$host$request_uri;
            add_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            break;
        }
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
      }

    location / {
            proxy_cache my_cache;
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
            add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            # CSS and Javascript
            location ~* \.(?:css|js|map)$ {
                  expires 1y;
                  access_log off;
                  add_header Cache-Control "public";
                  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com" always;
            }

            # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
            location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|webp|gif|png|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
                  expires 1y;
                  access_log off;
                  add_header Cache-Control "public";
                  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com" always;
            }

            location ~* \.(?:svg)$ {
                  expires 1y;
                  access_log off;
                  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com" always;
                  add_header Cache-Control "public";
            }
    
      }

      location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5100;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS';
      }
      
}
```